# Sonar doesn't import coverage.xml result

Tags: maven, grails, groovy, sonarqube, cobertura

I'm using SonarQube 5.1, sonar-runner 2.4, grails 2.4.4 and cobertura.
I am able to generate a coverage.xml file but then using sonar-runner or mvn sonar:sonar doesn't show any test coverag in SonarQube dashboard...nothing...
Any idea?

sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=test
sonar.projectName=test
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src/java,src/groovy,grails-app/assets,grails-app/services,grails-app/controllers,grails-app/domain,grails-app/views

sonar.language=grvy
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/test-reports
sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath=target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
```

---

and here is the trace of sonar-runner:

```
  C:\Temp\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe"  -cp "C:\Temp\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\lib\sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar" "-Drunner.home=C:\Temp\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4" "-Dproject.home=C:\test" org.sonar.runner.Main

SonarQube Runner 2.4

Java 1.7.0_71 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)

Windows 7 6.1 amd64

INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\Temp\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\conf\sonar-runner.properties

INFO: Project configuration file: C:\test\sonar-project.properties

INFO: Default locale: "no_NO", source code encoding: "UTF-8"

INFO: Work directory: C:\test\.\.sonar

INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1

INFO  - Load global repositories

INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=384ms

INFO  - Server id: 20150918133629

INFO  - User cache: R:\Users\kho\.sonar\cache

INFO  - Install plugins

INFO  - Install JDBC driver

INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

INFO  - Initializing Hibernate

INFO  - Load project repositories

INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=255ms

INFO  - Load project settings

INFO  - Load technical debt model

INFO  - Apply project exclusions

WARN  - 'sonar.dynamicAnalysis' is deprecated since version 4.3 and should no longer be used.

INFO  - -------------  Scan Abonnementsregisteret

INFO  - Load module settings

INFO  - Language is forced to grvy

INFO  - Load rules

INFO  - Base dir: C:\test

INFO  - Working dir: C:\test\.sonar

INFO  - Source paths: test/unit, test/integration, src/java, src/groovy, grails-app/assets, grails-app/services, grails-app/controllers

grails-app/domain, grails-app/views

INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: no_NO

INFO  - Index files

INFO  - 23 files indexed

INFO  - Quality profile for grvy: Sonar way

INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor

INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=47ms

INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor

INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=9ms

INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor

INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=111ms 

INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor

INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=34ms

INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor

INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=67ms

INFO  - Sensor CodeNarc

INFO  - Executing CodeNarc

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 72ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report1.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=0) 4030ms

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report2.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=2) 600ms

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report3.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=0) 158ms

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 0ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report4.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=5; p3=0) 472ms

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report5.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=0) 84ms

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 0ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report6.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=10; p3=2) 1271ms

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report7.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=7; p3=0) 562ms

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report8.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=0) 241ms

INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules

INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\profile.xml]

INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.

INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.

INFO  - Report file [C:\test\.sonar\codenarc\report9.xml] created.

CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=0) 81ms

INFO  - Sensor CodeNarc (done) | time=12286ms

INFO  - Sensor GroovySensor

INFO  - GMetrics completed: 542ms

INFO  - Sensor GroovySensor (done) | time=1091ms

INFO  - Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor

INFO  - Analyzing Cobertura report: target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml

INFO  - Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor (done) | time=338ms

INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor

INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=45ms

INFO  - Sensor GroovySurefireSensor

INFO  - parsing C:\test\target\surefire-reports

WARN  - Reports path not found: C:\test\target\surefire-reports

INFO  - Sensor GroovySurefireSensor (done) | time=28ms

INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor

INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for grvy

INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled

INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=309ms

INFO  - No quality gate is configured.

INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-09-18)

INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-08-19, analysis of Tue Sep 15 17:12:33 CEST 2015)

INFO  - Execute decorators...

INFO  - Store results in database

INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 83ms, dir size=9 KB

INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 279ms, zip size=13 KB

INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 101ms

INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/test

INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.

INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution that works for me.
I might help others:
I ended up running the following:

```
grails test-app unit: -echoOut -coverage -xml -nopost --non-interactive --plain-output --stacktrace --verbose
```

Then the coverage result showed up.

Good luck!

Comment: Check allso that you have correct "sonar.sources" path in your sonar-project.properties file

Comment: Allso sonar-runner should be used.